# symfony2 comparing hidden field with its hash with form validation

Tags: symfony, validation, custom-validators

I would like to know how to compare fields in symfony2 form with custom validation.
In particular I want to compare a simple hidden field with its hash.

```
<input type="hidden" name="smoke" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="smoke_hash" value="kahsjkdasjkdh3iuy84932798" />
```

Something like "repeated Field" but validated with my own logic.

But more something like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\HashMatchString;

$builder
    ->add('smoke', 'hidden', array(
            'data' => 1,
        )
    )
    ->add('smoke_hash', 'hidden', array(
            'constraints' => array(
                new HashMatchString('smoke')
            ),
        )
    )
;
```

[Form Goodness in Symfony 2.1](http://symfony.com/blog/form-goodness-in-symfony-2-1)

I’ve already see the solution of Steven Brown (http://www.yewchube.com/2011/08/symfony-2-field-comparison-validator/) but is one year ago with multiple touches on core files...

**SOLVED**
I’ve created a gist: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/4133261)

Answer (score 0):

Just add validation method to your entity http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#getters

Comment: Yes, is a solution... but its annoying adding method to entity every time I’ve some hidden fields and much important the field that are hidden is not always the same so I want to apply my validation with my custom validator directly in form like this [Form Goodness in Symfony 2.1](http://symfony.com/blog/form-goodness-in-symfony-2-1)